# How to add email to the screen?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have this code, the problem is that when I finish the program and start again, it does not save the email on the screen, only in `email.txt`.

How can I add the email and password on the screen, being that even when I restart the file the email still appears on the screen, not only in `email.txt`?

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
import tkinter.messagebox

roots = Tk()
roots.title("Email's save")
roots.geometry("500x500")

e = Entry(roots)
e.grid(row=0, column=1)
e.focus_set()

p = Entry(roots, show="*")
p.grid(row=1, column=1)
p.focus_set()

textEmail = StringVar()
textPassword = StringVar()


def callback():
    textEmail.set(textEmail.get() + e.get() + "\n")
    textPassword.set(textPassword.get() + p.get() + "\n")


def cleargrid():
    textEmail.set("")
    textPassword.set("")


def delete():
    answer = tkinter.messagebox.askquestion('Delete', 'Are you sure you want to delete this entry?')
    if answer == 'yes':
        cleargrid()

def save():
    email_info = e.get()
    password_info = p.get()

    file = open("emails.txt", "a")
    file.write(email_info)
    file.write("\n")
    file.write(password_info)
    file.write("\n")
    file.write("=" * 20)
    file.close()


def EmailPassword():
    email = Label(roots, text="Email: ", font=('Courier', 14))
    email.grid(row=0, sticky=W)

    passoword = Label(roots, text="Password: ", font=('Courier', 14))
    passoword.grid(row=1, sticky=W)

    saved_email = Label(roots, text="Saved Email", font=('Courier', 14))
    saved_email.grid(row=15, column=0)

    saved_password = Label(roots, text="Password", font=('Courier', 14))
    saved_password.grid(row=15, column=15)

    write_email = Label(roots, textvariable=textEmail, font=('Courier', 14))
    write_email.grid(row=20, column=0)

    write_password = Label(roots, textvariable=textPassword, font=('Courier', 14))
    write_password.grid(row=20, column=15)

    btn_save = Button(roots, text="Save", command= lambda:[callback(), save()])
    btn_save.grid(row=10, column=2, sticky=W)

    btn_del = Button(roots, text="X", fg="red", command=delete)
    btn_del.grid(row=60, column=20)

    roots.mainloop()

EmailPassword()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Delete your current 'emails.txt'. It isn't formatted properly for the below to work.
- Change `save` to this. Note the `\n` after your `=*20`

  ```
  def save():
      with open("emails.txt", "a") as f:
          f.write(f'{e.get()}\n{p.get()}\n{"="*20}\n')
  ```
- Add this function

  ```
  def get_emails():
      try:
          with open("emails.txt", "r") as f:
              for i, line in enumerate(filter(lambda t: t != f'{"="*20}\n', f.readlines())):
                  if not i%2:
                      textEmail.set(f'{textEmail.get()}{line}')
                  else:
                      textPassword.set(f'{textPassword.get()}{line}')
      except FileNotFoundError:
          pass
  ```
- Add this line right before `roots.mainloop()`

  ```
  get_emails()
  ```

**aside:**

Are you really going to store non-encrypted email and password information in a text file?

Answer (score 1):

In order for the email address to appear at the beginning, you have to get that information from the file. Just add another function that opens the file (if present), reads the address and sets the variable `textEmail`

```
def set_email():
    try:
        file = open("emails.txt", "r")
        emails = file.readlines()
        last_address = emails[-2][:-1] # line before last line without the line break
        file.close()
        textEmail.set(last_address)
    except:
        pass ## There was no file "emails.txt"
```

If you call this function after the variable `textEmail` is defined, you will have the address when the window is loaded.